# Controlling power management with systemd-networkd

Tags: wireless, network-manager, power-management, systemd-networkd

I was having Wi-Fi issues on Ubuntu 22.04 terminal edition. I tried to disable power saver by setting the networkmanager config file. It never changed the state of wifi module and I finally figured out that systemd-networkd was being used instead and was the default in the OS image as networkManager did not come installed.

How can I change the power configuration of a WiFi module when systemd-networkd is being used as the control?

I look at the documentation and I didn't see a mention of power saving options.

My solution was to install TLP and disable power saving on the wifi but I shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: Read `man ethtool`. You may have to install the `ethtool` package.

Comment: How to change power settings with it?